# While function into other while doesn't work

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to make a simple program using python that code some text into numbers, I got that part right but my second while just work the first time.

Can you help me understand why?

I put some prints so you can see whats going on.

```
tabela = ['89', '56', '48', '66', '99', '87', '79', '72', '26', "jj", '36', '57', '12', '10', '72', '15', "qq", '88', '47', '73', '92', '23', "ww", "xx", '39', '30', " "]
abc = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'," "]
i = 0
i2 = 0
resultado = ''

print("Escreva a sua frase", end=" ")
texto = input()

while i<len(texto):
    print (i, "menor", len(texto))
    while i2<len(tabela):
        print (i2, "menor", len(tabela))

        print(abc[i2], texto[i])
    if abc[i2] == texto[i]:

        resultado = resultado + tabela[i]          
        print (resultado)
    i2 += 1

i += 1
```

Comment: Move the code from `if abc[i2] == texto[i]:` 4 spaces to the right.

Comment: You increment the iterator outside of the second loop. Put `i2 += 1` under `while i2<len(tabela):`

Comment: It is likely because i2 remains as len(table). At the end of the second while, put i2=0

Comment: @crowflu yes that's the way, but if i put it at the end of the while it will get into an infinite while

Comment: i have to put it under the first while of course! so it resets i2 till the first loop is over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have to put `i2 = 0` under the first while so it resets `i2` till the first loop is over